# How to use the json_decode/json_encode in PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am getting a problem in PHP. I am trying to pass the username/password from Android and checking the value in MySQL through PHP. While using `json_decode` and `json_encode`, `json_decode` works but `json_encode` does not work. But when I remove the `json_decode`, `json_encode` works, but I want both of them to work in my program.

Here is my code:

```
$a = $_POST['userpwd_value']; //Accesing the value from Android.

$b = json_decode($a); //Decoding android value using JSON.

$username = $b->{'username'}; //Assigning username from android to a variable.
$password = $b->{'password'}; //Assigning password from android to a variable.

echo $username.$password;

$check = mysql_query("select username,password from user where id=1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);

//if($row['username']==$username && $row['password']==$password)
    $output[]=$row;
//else
    //$output[]=array("value"=>"false");
print(json_encode($output));
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you try with print_r(json_encode($output))  to see what is the output

Comment: Have you made sure $row contains what you expect it to contain?  Maybe that's why json_encode isn't returning the expected value.

Comment: How about that you remove `echo $username.$password` from your code?

Comment: @Adnan it produces result in PHP but not in android

Comment: @ Crashspeeder yah i have checked the $row values @Gumbo json_decode will produce output but json_encode will not @ Michael J.V result doesnt change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) fails if the variable content is not correctly UTF-8 sequenced. If your database uses another charset, the variables contain special characters, then you should get an error there. (raise the [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting) level or check [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/json_last_error) to find out)

Another problem with your specific code is that you first output something else:

```
 echo $username.$password;
```

This will invalidate the JSON output as a whole. If you have leading garbage, your browser will not decode the returned variables correctly. Also don't forget to send the appropriate header with your result using`header("Content-Type: application/json");`

---

```
  $b=json_decode($_POST['userpwd_value']); 
  $username=$b->{'username'}; 
  $password=$b->{'password'};

  $check = mysql_query("select username,password from user where id=1");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
  $row = array_map("utf8_encode", $row);

  if ($row['username']==$username && $row['password']==$password) {
      $output[] = $row;
  } else {
      $output[] = array("value"=>"false");
  }
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  print(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: @mario: thanks for the suggestion but i could understand ur second suggestion can u please elaborate me

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your script, and `var_dump(json_last_error());` after the json_encode output.

Comment: No it is still not working.$a=$_POST['userpwd_value']; //accesing value from android

  $b=json_decode($a); //decoding android value using JSON

  $username=$b->{'username'}; //assigning username from android to a variable  
  $password=$b->{'password'};//assigning password from android to a variable  

  echo $username.$password;
when i remove this the code json_encode will work.

Comment: Yes that's interesting. Did you try the suggestion I made yet?

Comment: Why is the echo still in your code? And what does the `var_dump` say then?

Comment: I have made comment to echo part...and var_dump says error like Call to undefined function json_last_error() ...there is no problem that json_decode is working but only problem is in json_encode

Comment: Well, keep the echo removed. If json_last_error does not exist, you are using PHP 5.2 or before. But the `error_reporting` should have written out a warning. -- Anyway add `$row = array_map("utf8_encode", $row);` right after the `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: Check the update code. Otherwise I wouldn't know what could be the problem. It's impossible to debug remotely without details.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and but still not working.i am trying by another mothod..

Answer (score 0):

I would think there may be another level in the JSON-encoded data (`$a`). Does your echo statement show the correct username and password? If not, place `var_dump($b);` after your 
`$b = json_decode($a);` statement.

Comment: yah it is show the correct username and password from the android

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below two lines to the following.

Your original lines:

```
  $username=$b->{'username'};
  $password=$b->{'password'};
```

New lines:

```
  $username=$b->username;
  $password=$b->password;
```

After the replacement, check if it's working or not.